# How do we obtain the following identification

Tags: algebraic-topology

I don't understand geometrically why the identification below let us generate the shape on the right can someone explain or give me some intuition ?[image]

Comment: Try gluing the $a$ pieces together, and then the $b$ pieces in your mind/with some paper or cloth. This should give you a handle of sorts

Comment: Then you can maybe see that each pair of edges $a, b$ and $c,d$ and etc. gives you a handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the double torus case. We have the following octagon:

[image]

Start by cutting it along the diagonal depicted in the picture by a red dotted line. You'll get two squares with an "edge", i.e., the red line. Once one identifies both of those pieces together one gets two punctured torii: that is, $\Bbb T^2$ with a small disk removed from each. The boundary of the removed disk is precisely the image of the red dotted line under the quotient map.

Thus, glue back two copies of $\Bbb T^2 - D^2$ along the red circle. This is the image of the octagon under the quotient map. It's thus connected sum of two torii - which is precisely the double torus.

Comment: good I understand now